# How to verify smart contracts on different solidity versions

Tags: solidity, bytecode, swarm, verify

I'd like to build my own smart contract verify system with all solidity versions both on single file and multiple files just like what etherscan or other block explorer does.

I was able to verify for single file contract on version **0.5.16** following this [post](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/ethereum/verify-ethereum-contracts-using-web3-js-and-solc/) but with some modification.
This post said that runtime bytecode ends with `a165627a7a72305820` but in my case it was `a265627a7a72315820`. So I modified ending point of runtime bytecode as `627a7a72` for general use cases.

But when I am trying to verify multiple contracts created with solidity version **0.6.12** I recognized that this contract runtime bytecode does not include `627a7a72` as a trailing end.

All information of this contract is [here](https://ftmscan.com/address/0x8625e90a61A51f569eE94A38B3154D5023c6CBBe#code).

Here is what I have done for verification.

1. First I did a compilation on remix with the source code(2 files-FarmUtils.sol and  VaultFarmsZapperStaker.sol)
2. For both cases on remix and [ftmscan](https://ftmscan.com/address/0x8625e90a61A51f569eE94A38B3154D5023c6CBBe#code), abis were identical.
3. I got the runtime bytecode on remix with same settings on the ftmscan(  "optimizer": {
   "enabled": true,
   "runs": 400
   },)
   Here are bytecodes for both cases.

On [**Ftmscan**](https://ftmscan.com/address/0x8625e90a61A51f569eE94A38B3154D5023c6CBBe#code)

```
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
```

On **Remix**

```
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
```

Bytecode lengths:

- **Ftmscan**: 12668
- **Remix**: 12476

I made a comparison of them and they are the same till 12390th character.
After that from 12391 to 12453 meaning 64 characters (**32 bytes**) they are different.

Here is different parts.

- Ftmscan: `3230123b82c930f1c67bc875788ef28e85d5d02b06bd0e2377eea8322371a8a`
- Remix:      `dc42e2a2f3dbafcf33685dccc6db6e30dc2eeeb9b0720ec1db7e09c275e3412`

After that from 12454 to 12476 meaning 11 bytes they were same as `64736f6c634300060c0033`.
And at this point remix bytecode finishes and Ftmscan bytecode continues with `000000000000000000000000f491e7b69e4244ad4002bc14e878a34207e38c2900000000000000000000000077216b8c728097993e9ef0e1fe527fa4506fd6bc0000000000000000000000007416ccc4b26535ad0580f5bba0d4d237de8d9d52`

I found on [Ftmscan](https://ftmscan.com/address/0x8625e90a61A51f569eE94A38B3154D5023c6CBBe#code) that this is for constructor arguments.

Also I couldn't find anywhere `627a7a72` that I used as a trailing end point of runtime bytecode and am not sure if it's for solidity version or multiple contracts.

**So summing up my problems**

- How to verify smart contracts on both multiple and single files.
- How to get constructor arguments bytecode on above case

I am now totally confused and back to the starting point.
Any help will be really appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article is fairly old. I'd suggest taking a look at the current [docs on Contract Medatata](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/metadata.html). They contain these notes:

> The CBOR mapping can also contain other keys, so it is better to fully decode the data instead of relying on it starting with `0xa264`. For example, if any experimental features that affect code generation are used, the mapping will also contain `"experimental": true`.

> The compiler currently uses the IPFS hash of the metadata by default, but it may also use the bzzr1 hash or some other hash in the future, so do not rely on this sequence to start with `0xa2 0x64 'i' 'p' 'f' 's'`. We might also add additional data to this CBOR structure, so the best option is to use a proper CBOR parser.

In 0.4.24 metadata used to contain only the Swarm hash, which is why the starting byte was `0xa1`. The three higher bits say that it's a map (`101` = `5` = map in CBOR) and five lower ones say that the map contains only one key (`00001` = `1`). In contracts compiled with later versions the map contains 2 items (IPFS hash and the compiler version) which is why it changed to `0xa2`.

The following byte (`0x65`) is packed in a similar way - it represents the type and the length of the first mapping key. It changed to `0x64` because the Swarm hash stored under `bzzr0` key has been replaced with an IPFS hash stored under a key that is one byte shorter (`ipfs`).

For robust detection it's best not to make too many assumptions about how this metadata is structured. Use a heuristic to detect where it starts but then use a proper CBOR parser to decode it. I think it might be best to look only for keys and ignore the type/length bytes. Looking at [`CompilerStack::createCBORMetadata()` in solc 0.8.9](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.8.9/libsolidity/interface/CompilerStack.cpp#L1610-L1643), I see just a few possibilities:

- `ipfs`
- `bzzr1`
- `experimental`
- `solc`
- `bzzr0` (was present in older versions)

Changes to metadata are always listed in [compiler's changelog](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md) so keep an eye for newer versions but for the existing ones this should be about it.

Also, you only really need to strip this from the bytecode you get from the blockchain. For the sources you are compiling yourself you can use the `--metadata-hash none` flag to get bytecode without a metadata hash.

Having said that, I'd strongly recommend not to ignore metadata during verification. If you use the JSON input that the compiler accepts (rather than flattened sources) and use the right version of the compiler, you should really get the same exact bytecode, including metadata hash embedded in it. Metadata contains hashes of all source files, their paths and compiler options used to build the bytecode so if you ignore these differences, you'll be potentially accepting modified sources - files with misleading comments, completely different variable and contract names, changed licensing info or even extra code that got optimized out. Actually, having the metadata JSON and original sources is always enough to recreate compiler input that exactly reproduces the bytecode. This is why it's recommended to keep and publish the metadata (e.g. using [Sourcify](https://sourcify.dev/)).

The practice of ignoring metadata is outdated and comes from the limitations of older versions of the compiler and the verification tools. For example, in the past etherscan required you to submit a single source file, which is why a common strategy used by verification tools is to combine all your files into one. This requires an assumption that you can simply replace any import with the content of the corresponding file. This might have been true in the past but is not guaranteed to work now and new features that depend on separation between source units are planned. Since version 0.4.11 the compiler provides a standardized JSON interface and etherscan supports it too and this is the safer way to do verification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cameel. But unfortunately, I still can't understand how I can work out this. You said it is possible to generate exactly same compiled bytecode with same compiler version.  Can you explain how I can get this using `solc`. (or any other compilers). I am currently using `solc` and just created a new repository for your feedback. Can you give me any idea on this site or via that github repository? **github repo:** (https://github.com/kimiro34/solidity-contract-source-code-verifier-example)

Comment: Or can you let me know how can i get exactly same bytecode for this with solc [contract](https://ftmscan.com/address/0x8625e90a61A51f569eE94A38B3154D5023c6CBBe#code)

Comment: Commands what I have tried. `solc --bin --metadata-hash swarm -o multiple/output --overwrite --optimize --optimize-runs 400 multiple/VaultFarmsZapperStaker.sol`, `solc --bin --metadata-hash ipfs -o multiple/output --overwrite --optimize --optimize-runs 400 multiple/VaultFarmsZapperStaker.sol`, `solc --bin --metadata-hash none -o multiple/output --overwrite --optimize --optimize-runs 400 multiple/VaultFarmsZapperStaker.sol`, But not exactly same. All bytecodes were slightly different.

Comment: It's possible to generate the same bytecode but you have to use the same compiler options and have the same (relative) paths for files. For example if the file being compiled was in `contracts/X2.sol` dir, you have to include the `contracts/` in compiler input. If all contracts in the project were compiled with a single command, you won't get the same metadata if you compile each separately. This is why having either the original JSON input or metadata is important. Generally it's best to require the user to submit the JSON input for verification rather than just the files.

Comment: As for the repo you created, `X2.sol` seems to be the flattened source. You won't get the same metadata from that. It's basically no longer the same exact code. You need the original sources exactly as they were during compilation. If you don't have that then unfortunately ignoring metadata is all you can do, just be aware that such verification does not guarantee that the source has not been altered in ways that do not affect the bytecode.

Comment: `--metadata-hash none` above should not really give you different bytecode, just a truncated one with a different hash. The issue is that solc 0.5.16 (that's the version used in `X2.sol`) did not have this option so it will give you an error instead.

Comment: This comment section is not the best place to talk about this. Please drop by at the [#solidity](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity) channel if you want more help with this (or just post a new question).